# Rails: Change index based on selected value in dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, simple-form

I have two models:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cows
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :cows
end

class Cow < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location
end
```

Every location has an id, a name and three boolean values. A cow consists of an id, two strings and two dates and it also includes a location_id.

In my cow view I have a dropdown of every location. It gets updated automatically whenever I create, edit or delete a location.
[image]

Below the dropdown you can see all cows ever created. Afer that there is a form to add a new cow with the two string fields and two date fields.
[image]

Now I want two things: Whenever I select a value in the dropdown, the displayed cows should change. If I select for example location 2, only cows that have a location_id = 2 in the table should be shown. Also when I create a new cow, the id of the selected location should be saved as well (in this example location_id = 2 should be saved in the cow row when I click the button at the very bottom).

This is how the dynamic dropdown looks like in the cow index.html file:

```
  <%= simple_form_for Cow.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :location, Location.order('name').all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Ort auswählen" } %>
  <% end %>
```

And this is my cow controller:

```
  def index
    if (params[:location] && Location.all.collect(&:name).include?(params[:location][:name]))
     @cows = Cow.send(params[:location][:name].downcase)
    else
     @cows = Cow.all
    end
  end

  # (...)

  def create
    @cow = Cow.new(cow_params)
    # (...)
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cow
      @cow = Cow.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def cow_params
      params.require(:cow).permit(:ohrmarke, :hin, :weg, :stallnummer, :location_attributes => [:id])
    end
end
```

The edited index part just does not work. Perhaps because I have a dropdown for Cow.new and I don't have a submit button. Now the thing is: I need the dropdown (value) for a new cow but also want to  display cows that fit to the selected dropdown value. Also I don't want to use a submit button just for the dropdown box. Is there any solution for my problem? I googled so much but just can't find the right answer for my problem.

---

**Edit:**
I edited my cows controller and my index page:
**cow controller:**

```
def index
    @locations_all = Location.all
    if (params[:location] && cows = Cow.where(location_id: params[:location]))
      @cows = cows
      @location = Location.where(id: params[:location])
    else
      @cows = Cow.all
    end
end

# (...)

def create
  @cow = Cow.new(cow_params)
  # (...)
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_cow
    @cow = Cow.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def cow_params
    params.require(:cow).permit(:ohrmarke, :hin, :weg, :stallnummer, :location_attributes => [:id])
  end
```

**cow index.html:**

```
  <%= simple_form_for Cow.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :location, Location.order('name').all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Ort auswählen" } %>
    <ul>
      <% @locations_all.each do |loc| %>
        <li><%= link_to loc.name, @cows.index(location: loc.id) %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>


    <%= f.hidden_field :location_id, value: @location_id %>

    <table class="striped">
      <thead class="thead-default">
        <tr>
          <th>Ohrmarke</th>
          <th>Stallnr.</th>
          <th>Hin/Weg</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <!-- ... -->
      </tbody>
    </table><br>

    <%= f.input :ohrmarke, as: :string, input_html: { maxlength: 5 } %>
    <%= f.input :stallnummer, as: :string, input_html: { maxlength: 3 } %>

    <!-- datepicker not functional yet -->
    <input type="date" class="datepicker" id="hin" placeholder="hin">
    <input type="date" class="datepicker" id="hin" placeholder="weg">

    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Zuordnung speichern
      <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I have edited my answer based one your latest update. See if the new changes work for you. Considerer tagging as correct, if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Drop-down & Content**

This is a possible implementation for `cows_controller#index`.

```
def index
    @locations_all = Location.all
    if (params[:location] && cows = Cow.where(location_id: params[:location]))
      @cows = cows
      @location = Location.where(id: params[:location])
    else
      @cows = Cow.all
    end
end
```

There are however a few important points to be made and a few problems.
The code you're using for the drop-down assumes you're making a POST request which isn't necessary in this case. The same can be achieved with a simple `link_to`. In order for this to work, you'd have something similar to this:

```
<ul>
    <% @locations_all.each do |loc| %>
        <li><%= link_to loc.name, cows_path(location: loc.id) %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

---

**Form**

In order for the form to create a new `Cow` using the correct location you'd need to include a `hidden_field` inside it.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :location_id, value: @location.id %>
```

But this introduces a design problem. What happens when you haven't selected any `location` on the drop-down menu? There are plenty of ways to handle this problem, but my favorite solution is to hide the form in that case.

```
<% unless @location %>
    #form-block ...
<% end %>
```

This solutions seems ideal if `cows` can't be created without a specified `location`.

---

#### Edit

Ok, now that I can see you HTML. I can tell you what wrong. Your `simple_form_for` block is surrounding the whole view. Which is probably not what you want. `forms` are usually POST requests, so you only need those when you plan to send data, or create a new entry on a table. `link_to` is a GET request which you can request information to the server. This a small example of how my view would look like:

```
#drop-down menu
<div id="cow_menu">
    <ul>
        <% @locations_all.each do |loc| %>
            <li><%= link_to loc.name, cows_path(location: loc.id) %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>

#table
<table class="striped">
    # your table logic...  
</table>

#new Cow form
<%= simple_form_for Cow.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :location_id, value: @location_id %>
    <%= f.input :ohrmarke, as: :string, input_html: { maxlength: 5 } %>
    <%= f.input :stallnummer, as: :string, input_html: { maxlength: 3 } %>
    <%= f.submit "Zuordnung speichern", class="btn waves-effect waves-light"%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I replaced the index with your solution and added the <ul> part to my html, but had to use @cows_index instead of cows_index. Now I have three links on the page but if I click on one nothing happens, even if the cow rows have different location_ids in it. Also when I create a cow, the location id won't be saved. I edited my question with further details.

Comment: My bad `cows_index(location: loc.id)`  should be `cows_path(location: loc.id)`. This should solve the drop-down problem. Now the `location_id` not getting saved is something a little harder to solve without taking a look at your code. Try to include `:locationd_id` to your `params.require(:cow).permit()`

Comment: Thanks for the comment & the edit, the index now changes based on the dropdown selection. I guess the problem that the location_id won't be saved is because of the controller, I have to research this. I have one more question: Do you know how to get the selected name of the location? I have two headers where I want to insert the selected name but since the page reloads I don't know how to access the location name.

Comment: Sure. That's really simple to solve. Since we defined `@location` on you controller we can just access the location's name by using `@location.name`. Note that's only available if you have already selected one of the locations your drop-down menu.

Comment: It seems to me that you're a beginner on Ruby on Rails. So I would recommend you to take a look at [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org). It explains most of the basic stuff I went through. It should clarify most of your questions.